# Python Pandas: add two different data frames

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sum different data frames, say *dataframe a*, *dataframe b*, and *dataframe c*.

*Dataframe a* is defined within the python code like this:

```
a=pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,8), columns=[0])
a.iloc[:,0]=0
```

(*a.iloc[:,0]=0* is given to enable arithmetic operations, ie, replacing "NaN" with "Zero")

*Dataframe b* and *Dataframe c* are called from an excel sheet like this:

```
b=pd.read_excel("Test1.xlsx")
c=pd.read_excel("Test2.xlsx")
```

The excel sheets contain the same number of rows as *Dataframe a*. The sample is:

```
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

Now when I try to add, `b+c` gives fine output, but `a+b` or `a+c` give this:

```
   0   10
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN
5 NaN NaN
6 NaN NaN
7 NaN NaN
8 NaN NaN
```

Why is this happening, even after assigning numbers to *Dataframe a* ?
Please help.

Comment: I can't tell what you're doing because all I see is some code taken out of context.

Comment: can you add a sample of dataframe you are using and sample output? It would help if you also provide the code for generating the datafarme

Comment: ColdSpeed and Sahil, thank you very much for commenting. Sorry for the vague question. I have updated it. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas will take care of the indexing for you. You should be able to generate and add dataframes as show here

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame(list(range(8)))
b = pd.DataFrame(list(range(9,17)))
c = a + b
```

Using the code you provided to generate data produces a dataframe with only zeroes. Nevertheless, even if you generate two of those and add them, you will again get a dataframe with all zeroes.

```
a = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,8), columns=[0])
a.iloc[:,0] = 0
b = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,8), columns=[0])
b.iloc[:,0] = 0
c = a + b # All zeroes
```

I am also able to add all combinations such as `b+c`.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this didn't help. Everything is fine while adding the same type of data frames (excel data+excel data or defined data+defined data), which is given in your example. If I try to add "data a" (of your example), with a data called from an excel sheet, the code just gives "NaN".